# What's the difference between "rebuild links" and what cron does in xmlsitemap?

Tags: 7, users, xml-sitemap

Kind of a newbie question about the [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) module, I suppose...

I've got the module installed, and it's running, with the "XML sitemap node" module also installed and activated.  It's working, but I'm uncertain about how/when changes in node availability are reflected in the sitemap.  In my testing, I've changed a couple of nodes by modifying their node access records, making them inaccessible to the anonymous user (this is what the site will actually be doing).  If I refresh the `sitemap.xml` "file", the nodes still show up, even after running the sitemap's cron actions.  It's not until I run the "Rebuild links" action that the sitemap shows the proper thing.

I can see, and have hacked around with, a couple of places where this behavior might be controlled the "change frequency" dropdown in XML sitemap settings, or the frequency with which the cron job runs.  But the only thing that reliably changes the sitemap for me is "Rebuild links", and I understand that's not the right way to do it in a regular sense.  What is?  How/when will these changes get made in the site map, and where do I control it?